# xserver missing winauth.h header file

Tags: cygwin, xserver

good morning,

i am trying to make with cygwin for xserver but it keeps throwing missing winauth.h file.

```
InitOutput.c:68:10: fatal error: winauth.h: No such file or directory
   68 | #include "winauth.h"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~
```

in xserver/hw/xwin/ directory, i have winauth.c but missing header file for it.

in all versions i checked, they are all missing winauth.h file.

i tried to create a blank winauth.h file and it throws errors from it so I think that file is required.  where can i find this file?

Thank you!

Comment: send a mail to the Cygwin mailing list, the xserver pkg maintainer could help you ad clarify the matter

Answer (score 0):

It is inside the source package of the X server `xorg-server`

```
$ tar -tf xserver-xserver-cygwin-21.1.4-2.tar.bz2 | grep winauth
xserver-xserver-cygwin-21.1.4-2/hw/xwin/winauth.c
xserver-xserver-cygwin-21.1.4-2/hw/xwin/winauth.h
```

You can download the `src` package with Cygwin setup. It will be installed under `/usr/src/`

```
$ ls -1 /usr/src/xorg-server-21.1.4-2.src/
xorg-backtrace
xorg-server.cygport
xserver-xserver-cygwin-21.1.4-2.tar.bz2
xvfb-run
xvfb-run.1
```